# Are variable declarations in inner code blocks permitted in the B programming language?

Tags: b-lang

For example, is the following snippet legal in B?

```
int main() {
    auto i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        auto x; // Is this legal?
    }
}
```